# Extract text from enclosing parentheses using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `Manila (Philippines)` and want to replace it with only the substring `Philippines`. I tried using the following regex pattern, which works in Notepad++:

```
[^\(]+ \(([^\)]+)\)
```

However, I get an `undefined` result in JavaScript:

```
var x = "Manila (Philippines)";
console.log(x.replace(/[^\(]+ \(([^\)]+)\)/,$1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot the `"` around your replace pattern!

`console.log(x.replace(/[^\(]+ \(([^\)]+)\)/,"$1"));` will work correctly!

Comment: I tried this but the slashes around `/$1/` are also included in the result, like `/Philippines/`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated and tested the answer with `"`!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
var x = "Manila (Philippines)";
var result = x.match(/\((.+)\)/).pop();
//              regex for string contained in parentheses

console.log(result);
```